# Gradle add file to classpath, could not expand zip error

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have an xml file that I need to be added to the classpath.

```
dependencies {
    compile files("${rootProject.rootDir}${File.separator}log4j2.xml");
}
```

In another project i'm creating a uberjar using.

```
jar {
    from(configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) 
}
```

When adding the xml file the build fails with this error:

> Could not expand ZIP '/log4j2.xml'.

I can put the file in main/resources and it be embedded into the jar will but I don't want two copies of the file, one in the root project and another in the parent project.

Comment: You can't put an xml file in the classpath. Only directories and jar files.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Not sure what you mean by that, I'm pretty sure you can put  on a classpath any type of file you want

Comment: It looks like JB Nizet is correct, I put the file in a new directory and referenced it. See: `compile files("${rootProject.rootDir}${File.separator}newdir")` now the xml is placed in the classpath. Thanks.

Comment: Stop using `${File.separator}` just use forward slash `/` it works under windows and unix much prettier to read!